# Is implied volatility model specific in the context of options on stocks and indices?

Tags: black-scholes, equities, implied-volatility

I just wanted to clarify a few things around implied volatility which I've read in the Hull/Natenberg books, which I find quite confusing.

Both books refer to implied volatility in the context of a European option on a non-dividend paying underlying, and they calibrate the BS 1973 model to observed option prices and back solve for the volatility, which then gives the "implied volatility".

My question is whether this is the strict definition of implied volatility? i.e. is the "implied volatility" always the volatility calculated from observed prices using the basic BS 1973 model, at least in the context of stock indices and individual stocks?

Eg1: if I wanted to calculate the implied volatility on the S&P500 index (which are European options on a dividend paying underlying) at a certain strike and maturity - is it just a matter of calibrating the BS 1973 model to observed prices and back solving for the volatility?

Eg2: if I wanted to calculate the implied volatility on Microsoft (an American option on a dividend paying underlying) at a particular strike and maturity, would I just repeat the process in Eg1?

Any clarity on this is greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes. I suppose it should be called "the implied volatility under Black Scholes assumptions" but everyone just calls it "implied volatility". (And everyone realizes that the Black Scholes assumptions are not quite true in real life).

Comment: Thanks @noob2 - so just to be clear: both Eg1 and Eg2 are then correct if I am talking about computing the "implied volatility"? If so, and as I understand it, the BS 1973 model is the benchmark model for calculating "implied volatility" even though the model is not appropriate for the American options, dividends etc cases - yes?

Comment: Wait. Note that I said "BS assumptions" not "BS 1973 formula". (Maybe I should have said BS framework for stock price behaviour). When you apply BS assumptions (constant vol, lognormal iid returns, etc) you can value American options, discrete dividends etc perfectly well with tree methods (CRR etc) or other methods. For no dividends you can use explicit BS 1973 formula and for continuous dividends BSM 1973 formula. For options on futures there is Black 1976 formula. These I would all consider part of the "Black Scholes framework".

Comment: right I see - so basically what you're saying is that the "implied volatility" is just the volatility back solved from a class of pricing models which are consistent with the "BS framework" yes? This would make much more sense now actually.